# Is it possible to group the events based on certain parameter and running Flink CEP pattern in each group?

Tags: apache-flink

I have event like 
{ "hostname":"abc.com", "data":{}}
in a kafka topic. The events are json objects. My flink-kafka consumer is accessing these events. Now Inside flink CEP can I group these events based on hostname and on each group can I check for pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this you should key the stream by the hostname, with something like `stream.keyBy(e -> e.hostname)`, and then apply the pattern to the keyed stream.

Also of interest is that Flink 1.7 has added support for using [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/table/streaming/match_recognize.html) to do pattern detection. You might find it easier to express what you are trying to do with stream SQL and MATCH_RECOGNIZE.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It gave me some idea about different streaming in flink